# What sources identify Si'la, a jinn appearing in shape of a women, and Arwah, spirits which can be seen by children?

Tags: source-identification, jinn

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon) claims that there is a Jinn called Si'la.

> Si'la, a jinn appearing in shape of a women, who seduces men and tries
>   to capture them and making them dancing.

And Wiki also claim that there is a spirit named Ruh or Arwah for plural that children can see.

> Arwah, spirits which can be seen by children.

Where do these come from, are they real and how can children see the Arwah?

Answer (score -1):

Arwah is the arabic word for spirits, and only human spirits are called arwah in islam. not evils or jinn.

about the jinn, they are just other creatures, they have no power or control over humans, until they are explicitly called, using black magic, this could be done for purpose of sex like in  "Black Tantra" where all those names come from. this is really one of the biggest sins, and will take you straight out of islam.

but in usual cases this will not likely to be happened without black magic.

If you stay close to Coran and praying regularly to allah, nothing can harm you or your children.

Comment: Can you give a link to 'Black Tantra'?